# Calculating entropy in Python using a C function with ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to use a C function to calculate the Sahnnon entropy within a Python script, using the ctypes library.

I have consulted some tutorials, and according to what I understood, the C code can be something like this (I called "entropy.c":

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float entropy(float *p, int n)
{

   int i;
   float ent;

   ent = 0.0;
   for(i=0; i< n; i++)
   {
      if(p[i] > 0.0)
      {
         ent += -p[i] * (double) log( (double) p[i]);
      }
    }

   return ent;
}
```

In the C code, there is a variable array (p) that represents the distribution to which the entropy must be calculated.

Now I have converted this to a "shared object" file in the usual way:

```
$ gcc -fPIC -shared -o entropy.so entropy.c
```

So from my understanding, the code in Python would have to look something like this:

```
import ctypes

so_file="./entropy.so"

entropy=ctypes.CDLL(so_file)


n=ctypes.c_int(2)
p=(ctypes.c_float * 2)(0.25,0.75)

print(entropy.entropy(p,n))
```

However, regardless of p, I always get as a result:

```
$ python entropy.py
$ 2
```

I have tried to find a solution but could not find it. So the question is what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't tell Python the return type, so it guessed that it was `int`, wrongly, and thus read the return value from the wrong place (assuming you're on x86-64, it read from `eax` instead of `xmm0`) and interpreted it wrongly. Do `entropy.entropy.restype = ctypes.c_float` before `print(entropy.entropy(p,n))`.